# Add factor information as annotation in a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot that includes the number of samples for each plot. It shows information on two variables. My code looks as follows:

```
give.nint <- function(SCPT){return(c(y = median(SCPT) * 1.06, label = length(SCPT)))}

ggplot(aes(y = speed, x = LITH, fill = SET), data = SCPT) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.nint, geom = 'text') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.nloc, geom = 'text')
```

This works! nint represents the number of samples in my SCPT table.

Now I want to plot something else. All samples are distributed over a number of sites, or locations (hence nloc) This number is the second number I want to show in my boxplot. The locations can be identified using the Name column from the table (or X and/or Y). I determine number of samples per location using;

```
give.nloc <- function(SCPT){return(c(y = median(SCPT) * 0.94, label = length(unique(SCPT$Name))))}     #[FIRST ATTEMPT]
give.nloc <- function(SCPT){return(c(y = median(SCPT) * 0.94, label = length(unique(SCPT[,2]))))}      #[SECOND ATTEMPT]

ggplot(aes(y = speed, x = LITH, fill = SET), data = SCPT) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.nint, geom = 'text') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.nloc, geom = 'text')
```

Now these functions are very similar to that of nint, but somehow, I cannot define the label like this.

At my first attempt, I got this warning message:

> Computation failed in `stat_summary()`: $ operator is invalid for
>   atomic vectors

The second attempt resulted in this warning message:

> Computation failed in `stat_summary()`: incorrect number of dimensions

I am now thinking about adding another column to my dataframe that contains the number of locations for all lith-set combinations (those are the factors in aes(), so for each lith-set combination a box is plotted), but I'd rather keep the data as clean as possible... do you have any idea?

For clarity, here's part of the data in my table - I omitted some of the variables that are not relevant to this question.

```
'data.frame':   4857 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ SET    : Factor w/ 2 levels "2014","2015": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Name   : chr  "SITE1" "SITE1" "SITE1" "SITE1" ...
 $ X      : num  111221 111221 111221 111221 111221 ...
 $ Y      : num  416143 416143 416143 416143 416143 ...
 $ speed     : num  150 150 140 120 ...
 $ STRAT  : chr  "Q" "Q" "R" "R" ...
 $ LITH   : chr  "A" "B" "B" "B" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `median(SCPT)` indicates that `SCPT` is a vector. If indeed it is a vector, the warning messages makes sense

A summary function only operate on a single vector of values. Don't think stat_summary is the solution if you want to bring in more variables in to summaries.

Comment: I see I have removed an (important) sentence in my question; for give.nint, the function works just fine. I only get the error message for give.nloc (and only when trying to plot it, not independently!). I think the problem lies within the label.

Comment: In `give.nint` you use `median` and length on `SCPT`. Which makes sense for vectors. In `give.nloc` (first and second attempt) you refer to `SCPT` as if it's a data.frame. If `SCPT` was indeed a data.frame, then `median(SCPT)` in `give.nint` would produce an error.

Comment: Ah okay, so it uses the median and length of the speed-data (vector). And in nloc, I need information from a different column from the table, while the function only receives data about 'speed', not the whole table, am I correct?
Then I should find another way to find the right information (number of unique locations per STRAT-LITH combination) and plot this as a label.

Comment: Exactly, all summary functions are called with a single vector of values. Now I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but unfortunately I don't have the answer at hand. Maybe stat_summary isn't the right way to go after all.